# How can I make the wave height smaller towards the outside with geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, texturing, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

Hello, that´s my first post here. Hopefully you can help me. :)
I connected a "Wave-Texture" to an "Extrude Mesh". In between I have a "Float Curve" and "Map Range" for better control of the look.

I want to do a wave animation. For that I want to insert keyframes to the "Phase Offset" in "Wave Texture". Now I want the waves which go outwards should become smaller unstil they dissapeared (getting flat). In my geometry node they have all the same heigh. I tried different things, but I couldn´t find a solution.

[image]

My theory is, that I have to change something in "Map Range" with the "To Max"-Value. Something with an Offset which lowers the value of the height of the waves if they leaving the centre. I would really appreciate the help.

Your

*PurpleSenf*

Comment: Hello and Welcome! You could mix the *Wave Texture* with a *Gradient Texture*, which is set to *Spherical*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options for this, but the most obvious solution would be to control the *Wave Texture* directly with a spherical gradient.

This could look like this:

[image]

Since your mesh has a dimension of 100m, you would have to scale the position vectors according to your wishes, because the node `Gradient Texture` works in a range of 1x1.

You can connect the output *Fac* with the node `Float Curve` or `Map Range` to get the desired result.

And at the end you use this value as multiplier for your *Wave Texture*.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution!